# Handling JSON data with irregular formating?

Tags: r

What I have many observations of json data that I got from an API that I'm trying to get "FIPS" into a data frame. Not every pull was successful, leaving null values and irregular formatting. When I try just the first pull,

```
    library(rjson)
    test<-"{\"status\":\"OK\",\"responseTime\":9,\"message\":[],\"Results\":{\"block\":[{\"envelope\":{\"maxy\":11.11111111,\"minx\":-11.11111111,\"maxx\":-11.1111111111,\"miny\":11.01111111111},\"geographyType\":\"BLOCK2010\",\"FIPS\":\"11111111111\"}]}}"
    test1<-fromJSON(test)
    names(test1)

    test1$Results$block$FIPS
    test.block.df<-as.data.frame(test1$Results$block$FIPS)
```

On a reproducible example:

```
rep<-c("{\"status\":\"OK\",\"responseTime\":10,\"message\":[\"No Block results found\"],\"Results\":{\"block\":[]}}", "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"responseTime\":9,\"message\":[],\"Results\":{\"block\":[{\"envelope\":{\"maxy\":00.0000000000,\"minx\":-00.000000000,\"maxx\":-00.00000000,\"miny\":00.0000000000000},\"geographyType\":\"BLOCK2010\",\"FIPS\":\"111111111121\"}]}}"  )
rep1<-fromJSON(rep)
names(rep1)
rep1$result$block
```

But after this, I cannot parse down to FIPS after this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks likee in this  case data has  two responses which is a json "record" format that is sometimes used. The clue is the sequence `} {`  Check if the two structures are actually separated by new line and try  `readLines` to get each line separately and apply `fromJSON` to each line.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues: 1) The number format for 00.0000 is not handled by jsonlite. 2) each request can return multiple responses, each formatted as an independent json structure

```
library(jsonlite)
rep<-c("{\"status\":\"OK\",\"responseTime\":10,\"message\":[\"No Block results found\"],\"Results\":{\"block\":[]}}", "{\"status\":\"OK\",\"responseTime\":9,\"message\":[],\"Results\":{\"block\":[{\"envelope\":{\"maxy\":00.0000000000,\"minx\":-00.000000000,\"maxx\":-00.00000000,\"miny\":00.0000000000000},\"geographyType\":\"BLOCK2010\",\"FIPS\":\"111111111121\"}]}}"  )

## jsonlite seems to choke on the number format 00.0000,
rep_fixed <- gsub("\\:\\-?00\\.", "\\:0.", rep)

# multiple results are returned each time, to apply to each structure 
rep1 <- lapply(rep_fixed, fromJSON)
str(rep1)

rep1[[2]][['Results']][['block']]

# envelope.maxy envelope.minx envelope.maxx envelope.miny geographyType         FIPS
#             0             0             0             0     BLOCK2010 111111111121
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The number format I had changed because these are coordinates to individual's addresses, format I changed it to is regrettable.  This answer is very helpful.